# Iterating over a lot of JSON files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following code, All I want to do is iterate over a bunch of JSON files - one by one - until I get to the end, outputting the timestamp of each object within each file.

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Get the contents of the directory and loop over it.
fs.readdir('./historical', function(err, list)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        // Get the contents of each file on iteration.
        var filename = list[i];

        fs.readFile("./historical/" + filename, function(err, data)
        {
            for (var index in data)
            {
                index = JSON.parse(index);
                console.log(index.timestamp);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This really seems to struggle to do anything... I can't get it to actually work at all.

Also - I know for a fact that every item it the files does in fact have a timestamp value.

Comment: Where's `JSON.parse()` on `data` of each loaded JSON file?

Comment: I have edited my code to look as it does above - Still doesn't seem to actually work. :(

Comment: Please provide an example of json file.

Comment: Those are async calls you can't loop them with a simple `for` you need to use Async module https://github.com/caolan/async or something like node-walk https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk

Answer (score 4):

It's wrong to use `for (var index in data)` loop the way you did it. You need first parse json file to get json object

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then you can manipulate your json object as you wish. It would be better if you provide json file example. But I described two examples just in case.

**Example 1:**
If json file represents an object then use the following code

```
console.log(parsedData.timestamp);
```

**Example 2:**
If json file represents an array of objects then use the following code

```
for (var index in parsedData) {
    console.log(index.timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the data is a `buffer` which contains binary data.
Actually, data is only a `string` if you specify an encoding.

I took the liberty to update your entire script to a more recent javascript version.
And to add a fileextension filter.

```
import { readdir, readFile } from "fs";
import * as path from "path";

const dirName = path.join(__dirname, "historical");
readdir(dirName, (err, fileList) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    const filename = fileList[i];
    if (!filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".json")) continue;

    const fullFilename = path.join(dirName, filename);
    readFile(fullFilename, { encoding: "utf-8" },
      (err, data) => {
        try {
          const fileContent = JSON.parse(data);
          // todo print whatever you like to print, e.g. console.log(fileContent);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(`error while parsing file: ${fullFilename}`);
        }
      });
  }
});
```